# Specify default value in Select (Laravel CRUD)

Tags: laravel, select

I am trying to learn Laravel CRUD and I can't seem to find a good answer on how to select default value for drop down menus when doing the update/edit stuff.
[image]

I was able to get the project name to be correct with this `value="{{ $kanban->title }}"`

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="project name" value="{{ $kanban->title }}" class="border-2 rounded px-2 py-1 focus:outline-none">
```

However when I do a similar thing for options, it doesn't work.

```
<select name="color" id="icon_color" class="border-2 rounded pl-2 pr-10 py-1 focus:outline-none" value="{{ $kanban->color }}" class="form-control">
```

I understand you can pick `selected` to choose the default value, but when editing it would be helpful if the default selected would be what the user picked originally.

This is like the full code, if anyone can link to some documentation that can explain how this works would be much appreciated as well.

```
<select name="color" id="icon_color" class="border-2 rounded pl-2 pr-10 py-1 focus:outline-none" value="{{ $kanban->color }}" class="form-control">
    <option value="text-blue-500 bg-blue-300">Blue</option>
    <option value="text-red-500 bg-red-300">Red</option>
    <option value="text-green-500 bg-green-300">Green</option>
    <option value="text-yellow-500 bg-yellow-300">Yellow</option>
    <option value="text-gray-500 bg-gray-300">Gray</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `select` tag does not have a `value` attribute. the supported attributes for the select tag can be found on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). so whether you set a `value` attribute or not it won't make any change on `options`. you have to use `selected` attribute on an `option` element to specify default option.

```
<select name="color" id="icon_color" class="border-2 rounded pl-2 pr-10 py-1 focus:outline-none" class="form-control">
    <option value="text-blue-500 bg-blue-300" @if ($kanban->color == 'text-blue-500 bg-blue-300') selected @endif>Blue</option>
    <option value="text-red-500 bg-red-300" @if ($kanban->color == 'text-red-500 bg-red-300') selected @endif>Red</option>
    <option value="text-green-500 bg-green-300" @if ($kanban->color == 'text-green-500 bg-green-300') selected @endif>Green</option>
    <option value="text-yellow-500 bg-yellow-300" @if ($kanban->color == 'text-yellow-500 bg-yellow-300') selected @endif>Yellow</option>
    <option value="text-gray-500 bg-gray-300" @if ($kanban->color == 'text-gray-500 bg-gray-300') selected @endif>Gray</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting FormCollectivewith laravel. That gives you easy to code in blade templates.

```
$data = [
'text-blue-500 bg-blue-300' => Blue,
'text-red-500 bg-red-300' => Red,
'text-green-500 bg-green-300' => Green,
'text-yellow-500 bg-yellow-300' => Yellow,
'text-gray-500 bg-gray-300' => Gray,
];

//$defaultValue = value from db if update else default value
{!! Form::select('size', $data , $defaultValue)!!}
```

You can find more
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Will check out the documentation.